# Why this "if statement" won't work in partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In some cases, it doesn't have `tag` argument just like this below.
So I put <%= tag + ',' if tag %>, but it gets this error

> ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)):

How can I solve?

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'layouts/social_like', :url => root_url, :title => @title %>
```

**layouts/_social_like.html.erb**

```
....
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-lang="en" data-hashtags="<%= tag + ',' if tag %>hash2,hash3,hash4">Tweet</a>
....
```

Comment: @pst it didn't work either. same result:(

Comment: doesnt your tag variable conflict with the tag rails helper ?
[tag helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag)

Comment: I don't think so. Because I tried `tag_name` too

Comment: I am not sure.. but it would be good to rename your variable onto something other than `tag` though.  Since if your variable doesnt exist it will fall back to calling the rails helper `tag` instead where you would get an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline if statements don't really work well (at all?) in ERB. You can do this with a ternary operation:

```
...data-hashtags='<%= tag ? "#{tag}," : "" %>hash2,hash3,hash4'>
```

Answer (score 0):

`tag` is a rails helper method that takes one arg; ruby thinks you are trying to call it without args. Rename your variable, and it should work.